# A question about the factors of reducible multilinear polynomial.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, factoring

Suppose that $P\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a multilinear polynomial and suppose that
$$
P=Q_1Q_2\cdots Q_n
$$
where each $Q_i\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is non-constant.

**Comment**: We say that a polynomial $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is *multilinear* it each of its monomials is a constant times a product of distinct variables. For example, $xy+2z+xz$ is multilinear.

**The problem:** I want to prove that the factors $Q_i$ are

(a) unique (up to a permutation of factor and multiplication by constants)

(b) themself multilinear

(c) have disjoint variables.

**My Attempt:**

Regarding (a), I guess that it follows from the fact that $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is UFD.

Regarding (b) and (c), suppose that $x_i$ is a variable in $P$. If we assign $x_j=1$ to all other variables, then we get an identity
$$
P(x_i)=Q_1(x_i)Q_2(x_i)\cdots Q_n(x_i).
$$
in $\mathbb{R}[x_i]$. Since $P$ is multilinear, it follows that the degree of $x_i$ is $1$. Therefore, $x_i$ appears exactly in one of the $Q_i$, and in degree $1$.

Is that proof holds?